# Send html through @Url.Action call

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

Was under the impression that .html() resulted in a string being created -- so thought that I could use var htmlBody to collect the html as a string and then pass it via the @Url.Action call using the .replace() method.

When debugging I see that the .replace() method works (i.e., url = "/Home/DidItWork?testEmail=\n etc.) but unfortunately that's where it starts to mess up.

It appears that I'm passing an object as opposed to the string that I wanted to send. If that's the case, how do I send html through a @Url.Action call? Because keep getting `"Error: Internal Server Error. Status: error. Console: [object Object]"` when trying to use the following code:

**_layout.cshtml**

```
@*script for someone who presses the send/email button*@ 
<script>
$("#sendButton").click(function () {
    //alert("Send button pressed");
    var htmlBody = $("#myModal .modal-body").html();
    var url = '@Url.Action("DidItWork", "Home", new { testEmail = "_blah_"})';
    url = url.replace('_blah_', htmlBody);
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function (result) {
            alert("Success. It worked." + htmlBody);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
            alert("Sorry, there was a problem! Error: " + errorThrown + ". Status: " + status + ". Console: " + xhr);
            console.log("Hello");
            console.log("Error: " + errorThrown);
            console.log("Status: " + status);
            console.dir(xhr);
            console.log("Good-bye");
        },
    });
    // return false to cancel the default action and leave the AJAX call
    return false;
});
</script>
```

HomeController.cs

```
public async Task<ActionResult> DidItWork(string testEmail)
    {
            var manager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = "user name", Email = "username@gmail.com" };
            var result = await manager.CreateAsync(user, "passwordGoesHere1!");
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await manager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", testEmail);

                return View();
            }

            //AddErrors(result);
            return View();    
    }
```

Comment: If you're using chrome, I'd suggest you open the debugger's network tab and view the actual error being returned in the Xhr request, you'll get the exact error message (yellow screen of death).

Comment: `$("#myModal .modal-body").html();` will return the actual markup of everything inside the element with `id = myModal` (which would probably fail anyway because of the tags being invalid). Not really sure what you are trying to do - are you wanting to send the value of a textbox that's within the modal?

Comment: Why are you returning all the markup of a modal to the server? You need to encode the string and URLS have length limits.

Comment: Missing an `encodeURIComponent` in there it looks like... (Also probably need to `[AllowHtml]` on your action.)

Comment: Stephen, I have an accordion that has a user select an answer before moving on to the next question. Once they've picked their answers (via a radio button) they're presented with a prompt that they can edit or send via a modal. I figured since the modal shows exactly what they are going to send that I could just copy the text from there and send it. Erik, thanks. I'm using IE, along with VS2013, to debug so I'll look for the exact error there -- if I can't find it I'll check chrome. Brad, I tried but I wasn't able to use [AllowHtml] - encodeURIComponent encoded but not sure that's what I need

Comment: Then you need to get the values from the radio button groups. I suggest you add `console.log(htmlBody);` and inspect the output to understand why what your doing makes no sense. Your would need to post the view for the modal so we can understand what you trying to post back (your term `testEmail` does not make it very clear)

Comment: The console.log(htmlBody) output returns the same thing alert shows -- a block of html, similar to how html would look for a paragraph on a website. If I replace the part in code with `var htmlBody = "some text goes here";` it works fine. I did notice that during "some text goes here" there was a "xhr" key during `ajaxExtend( target, src )` versus an "error" key for when htmlBody is a block of html. Is there a way to somewhere tell it that the htmlBody should also have an "xhr" key?

Comment: As for testEmail I originally was trying to send an email address to test whether I could pass the variable, which I was able to. Figured once I could pass that I could replace it with the string version of the html (though poor assumption on my part).

Comment: Thanks everyone. I'm closing this question because I didn't realize I could just get the text from the modal -- I thought I could only get the html. Since I don't need to send html I thought it be best to close the question.

Comment: @NateHill, You need to post the values of your controls, not the html. You have not posted any code, but say you have a group of radio buttons named `Answer`, then your would do `data: { answer: $('input:radio[name=answer]:checked').val(); },`and post back to a method with a parameter named `answer`

Comment: Just needed to change `$("#myModal .modal-body").html();` to `.text()` to get it working. You're right, I needed to post more of my code to give a better idea. I left out that radio selections updated my modal's fill-in-the-blank variables as it went along so that my modal would have all the text in the end. `<script>
        $('[name="optradio6"]').on('change', function () {
            var value = $(this).val();
            switch (value) {
                case "6a":
                    $('#blank6', $('#myModal')).text('soon');
                    break;
            }
    })
    </script>`

Answer (score 0):

You should use POST instead of GET here.

I believe this "testEmail" parameter can be quite long and contain all sorts of characters. But URL has a maximum length. You can't use it to send a long string. And you also need to encode the testEmail value to pass it in the query string, e.g. changing '#' to '%23'.

Using POST can solve all the problems. The code is like below:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: {testEmail: testEmail},
    success: function (result) {
        alert("Success. It worked." + htmlBody);
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
        alert("Sorry, there was a problem! Error: " + errorThrown + ". Status: " + status + ". Console: " + xhr);
        console.log("Hello");
        console.log("Error: " + errorThrown);
        console.log("Status: " + status);
        console.dir(xhr);
        console.log("Good-bye");
    },
});
```

In addition, I think testEmail can only be a string. Why do you have an object for it here? This may raise another question here.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Not sure if I implemented it correctly but including the above resulted in "testEmail is undefined"

Comment: This has nothing to do with OP's issue (although he probably does want to specify `type: 'POST',`)

Comment: I'm closing this question because I didn't realize I could just get the text from the modal -- I thought I could only get the html. Since I don't need to send html I thought it be best to close the question. Apologies for taking up your time with a question that didn't need to be asked in the first place.